# Weird component in radio player interferes with FM functionality of the radio itself

Tags: radio, interference, frequency-modulation

[image: image of the cassette player part of the radio]

I got my hands on an old radio player which has both cassette player and FM/AM functionality. I got constant noises while playing on FM and it turns out to be some weird component on the cassette player section of the radio interferes with the FM.

I took the whole cassette player part out and now I don't get any noise from the FM radio. The weird component is magnetic and closed using a metal shield (the component is on top left connected to yellow and brown wires.) I think it might be a tape reader but why would it interfere with the FM functionality of the radio even when the cassette player circuitry is not active?

I don't know it may be a very silly question because these circuits are ancient but I'm curious why it interferes with the FM.

Comment: The metal thing with the yellow and brown wires is a normal tape read head - there's nothing "weird" about it.  If there's noise getting into the FM receive audio from the tape read head, then there's something wrong with the circuitry the read head is connected to.  The read head itself shouldn't cause problems.  More likely something wrong in the switching circuits that switch the speaker amplifier from tape playback to FM audio.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I noticed that the noise reduces when I block the tape read head with my hands when the cassette reader part is within the radio(the cassette reader is powered up too). How could you explain this phenomenon?  Can magnetic fields from the tape read head really affect the FM audio ? I'm sorry I have never seen such uniquely shaped component in my life that's why it appeared somewhat weird to me

Comment: The tape head doesn't generate magentic fields, it detects them.  Whatever the problem is, it isn't the read head itself.  When you switch to FM receive, the tape head (or its amplifier) should be disconnected from the audio amplifier.  There's some else wrong.

Comment: It's not just a cassette player, but also a recorder! The metal thing is a read/write head; it does generate magnetic fields, but only while recording. So something is wrong in the wiring, and the unit is constantly trying to record audio... If you don't intend to uses the cassette unit, just cut the yellow and brown wires...

Comment: Best guess, by touching it, you form a (capacitive) path to earth which affect the offending circuit causing the noise.

Comment: Can you give us couple more pictures, including the main board and the whole radio/cassette player?

Answer (score 1):

When recording, the cassette record/playback head has an ultrasonic AC bias signal that interferes with the FM stereo 19kHz pilot tone and the FM stereo 38kHz modulation.
The cassette bias signal might even interfere with FM modern digital text of "what is playing".

Then maybe a fault in the circuit causes the tape bias signal to wrongly be on when the radio is playing FM.

Answer (score 0):

If the device has both an FM receiver and an audio tape player, then it must have some way of switching between those two signals to feed the speaker amplifier(s) with one or the other, but not both.  If you are getting noise from the tape player on top of the FM receiver audio, I would look at whatever is supposed to switch between the two.  This could be either a mechanical switch, or an electronic circuit controlled by a switch.

Answer (score 0):

The part in question is the read/write head, the other one in the picture (the blue one) is the erase head.

During playback the head is just a magnetic pickup, a voltage is induced in it by the magnetized tape passing by.

In record mode it will act as an electromagnet, magnetizing the tape with the audio signal and a high frequency bias signal. During recording the tape will first pass by the erase head which will apply a high level high frequency signal to erase anything already recorded. None of this *should* be active when the tape deck is not being used.

If you're getting interference from the tape deck there may be an oscillation in the circuitry, but an FM receiver is generally pretty resistant to RF noise. The noise may be getting into it through the shared power supply or through an audio path.

In something of that vintage the likely cause would be the electrolytic capacitors drying out, reducing the amount of power supply filtering or possibly causing some circuits to become noisy or oscillate.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that touching the tape head mitigates the interference doesn't mean it's coming from there.  It's possible, for instance, that changing the impedance of the ground plane is changing its EMC profile.

Check to see if it's a class D amp, since those can generate harmonics that directly demodulate as FM (actually PM) signals.  Also, check for digital components, and consider some power line conditioning.